# undefined method `error_message_on' after implementing simple private messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, private-messaging

I'm developing my first RoR website and I went through the steps to install simple_private_messages. Is this the way it's supposed to look? 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXsau.jpg

I get this error message when I click "compose":

```
 NoMethodError in Messages#new

Showing C:/app/views/messages/new.html.erb where line #5 raised:

undefined method `error_message_on' for #<#<Class:0x516e6d0>:0x516c0f0>
```

I went through all of the steps correctly (I believe).

Here's my route.db

```
  resources :users do
             resources :messages do
               collection do
                 post :delete_selected
               end
             end
           end
```

messages/new.html.erb

```
<% form_for @message, :url => user_messages_path(@user) do |f| %>
  <p>
    To:<br />
        <%= f.text_field :to %>
        <%= error_message_on @message, :to %>
  </p>
  <p>
    Subject:<br />
    <%= f.text_field :subject %>
    <%= error_message_on @message, :subject %>
    </p>
    <p>
      Message<br />
      <%= f.text_area :body %>
            <%= error_message_on @message, :body %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= submit_tag "Send" %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

Messages model

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

  is_private_message

  attr_accessor :to

end
```

Messages controller

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :set_user

  def index
    if params[:mailbox] == "sent"
      @messages = @user.sent_messages
    else
      @messages = @user.received_messages
    end
  end

  def show
    @message = Message.read_message(params[:id], current_user)
  end

  def new
    @message = Message.new

    if params[:reply_to]
      @reply_to = @user.received_messages.find(params[:reply_to])
      unless @reply_to.nil?
        @message.to = @reply_to.sender.login
        @message.subject = "Re: #{@reply_to.subject}"
        @message.body = "\n\n*Original message*\n\n #{@reply_to.body}"
      end
    end
  end

  def create
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])
    @message.sender = @user
    @message.recipient = User.find_by_login(params[:message][:to])

    if @message.save
      flash[:notice] = "Message sent"
      redirect_to user_messages_path(@user)
    else
      render :action => :new
    end
  end

  def delete_selected
    if request.post?
      if params[:delete]
        params[:delete].each { |id|
          @message = Message.find(:first, :conditions => ["messages.id = ? AND (sender_id = ? OR recipient_id = ?)", id, @user, @user])
          @message.mark_deleted(@user) unless @message.nil?
        }
        flash[:notice] = "Messages deleted"
      end
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end

  private
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    end
end
```

Comment: This is covered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646855/show-error-messages-next-to-field.  The short answer is that `error_message_on` was deprecated and is now gone.  There's a gem called [dynamic_form](https://github.com/rails/dynamic_form) that will add them to Rails 3, or you can follow some of the other suggestions in the Stack Overflow link.

Comment: thanks, that got rid of the "error_message_on" error but now I'm getting "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: to, subject, body". Do you know why this is? I always seem to get these errors even though I followed the steps exactly....

Comment: It sounds like you've got a lot of residual 2.3 code in a Rails 3 app.  There are quite a few things that have changed.  Google around for "upgrading rails 2 to 3" for some guides.  The protected attributes issue is covered in many other SO questions.  I suspect you're going to have more issues related to the upgrade, though, so finding a guide would be best.

Comment: Thanks. One last question - was this simple_private_messages plugin (as well as others) supposed to work out of the box or does it usually require customizing including defining all of the methods, etc. For example, right now it says that find_by_login is an undefined method after installing this plugin so I have to manually edit all of these