# Custom validation error messages for rails and their location?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, message

I want to display a custom error message for each validation that I have, I already accomplished this but not in it's total.

```
validates :first_name, presence: {message: "No escribistes tu nombre."}
validates :last_name, presence: {message: "No escribistes tu apellido."}
validates :mobile_phone, presence: { message: "No escribistes tu número de teléfono celular."}
validates :mobile_phone, length: { minimum: 10, message: "Número de celular debe contener mas de 10 números." }
```

This is working fine for except that it always shows before the error message:

```
FIRST NAME NO ESCRIBISTES TU NOMBRE.
LAST NAME NO ESCRIBISTES TU APELLIDO.
MOBILE PHONE NO ESCRIBISTES TU NÚMERO DE TELÉFONO CELULAR.
MOBILE PHONE NÚMERO DE CELULAR DEBE CONTENER MAS DE 10 NÚMEROS.
```

How do I get rid of the first `FIRST NAME, LAST NAME, MOBILE PHONE, MOBILE PHONE` that's written before the custom error message?

Also, I would like to know how to put, for example, the error message for the `first_name` to be under the first name field?

This is what I currently have:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
<!--<%= devise_error_messages! %>-->
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <div class="alert alert-danger"><%= msg %></div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>

<div>
  <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true, placeholder: 'Nombre' %>
  <%= f.text_field :last_name, placeholder: 'Apellido' %>
</div>
<div class="m-t">
  <%= f.telephone_field :mobile_phone, placeholder: '787-878-7878' %>
</div>
<div><%= f.submit "SIGN UP", class: 'custom-input-2 m-t' %></div>
<% end %>
```

How do I get rid of the list of errors and just show the errors under their specific fields instead.

Thank you.

Comment: This will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646855/how-to-show-error-messages-next-to-field

Comment: thanks I just have to add `<%= @user.errors[:first_name].join %>` and so on

Answer (score 1):

Change your forms error block to this to this:

```
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
  <% @user.errors.messages.each do |msg| %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger"><%= msg %></div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**OR**

Change it in locals/en.yml:

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        email: "E-mail address"
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            first_name:
              blank: "is required"
```

Since en.yml is for English so you'll have to create another .yml file for your language and it'll also help you by making your app internationalized. For details checkout [**`Rails Internationalization`**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)

Comment: thanks, I was able to do this while following this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325176/devise-custom-messages-when-validation-fails

Answer (score 0):

Following Nitin comment, I was able to make some modifications, I added the following:

```
<div>
  <%= raw @user.errors[:first_name].join + ("&nbsp")%>
  <%= @user.errors[:last_name].join %>
  <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true, placeholder: 'Nombre' %>
  <%= f.text_field :last_name, placeholder: 'Apellido' %>
</div>
```

That will display the error message for the specific variable.